# Wifi card causing High interrupts on Fedora 24

Tags: linux, fedora, wifi, interrupt

I am running Fedora 24 on my `MSI cx61 2QC` laptop. Occasionally, one of the processor's core becomes monopolized by high irqs from the rtl_pci(wifi) card.
The model of the wifi card is `RTL8723AE`.

`$ uname -a`

`Linux drpyser.localdomain 4.8.16-200.fc24.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 618:13:39 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`$ cat /proc/interrupts | grep rtl_pci`

```
 17:  127816570      57681     187040      66202   IO-APIC  17-fasteoi   rtl_pci
```

`$ lsmod | grep rtl_pci`

```
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8723ae
rtlwifi                73728  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723ae
mac80211              724992  2 rtl_pci,rtlwifi
```

Comment: Only Realtek can do something about this. Hardware interrupts come from the Realtek non-free firmware. It could be that the GPL driver is confusing it in some way but only Realtek would know what the problem is.